# How to call an overrided method when not casting explicitly its type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, types

I am on a tile game during my free time. Everything is fine except that I am stucked with some c# type issues.

Actually, I want to pop some randomized rewards when the player kills a mob. So I've got a Dictionary with hardcoded "RewardBlueprint" with all the data I need to instantiate the good Prefab and fill some properties with random values. Besides, each prefabs possess one script inherited from RewardHandler, a MonoBehaviour (e.g. RewardCoin, RewardShield, RewardWeapon, ...).

So my issue here is I don't know how to call the 'good' Setup function from the last inherited Class.

1. Monobehaviour > RewardHandler > RewardCoin.Setup(somedata) is calling the parent because not overriding it. So it's working.
2. Monobehaviour > RewardHandler > RewardWeapon.Setup(somedata) is calling the parent too even with the override.

My last and desperate try was to hardcode the type into the blueprint. But it doesn't work :p
So how do I call my weapon Setup and not the parent one ?

Here is how I create a new reward

```
internal void CreateReward(TileHandler tileHandler)
{
    //RNG the reward 
    ProbaItem proba = levelManager.currentLevel.rewardList.GetRandomItemByWeight();
    RewardBlueprint rewardBlueprint = Catalog.Rewards[proba.title];

    //Instantiate the rng-ed reward
    GameObject asset = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>(rewardBlueprint.location));

    IReward rewardHandler = asset.GetComponent(rewardBlueprint.component) as IReward;
    rewardHandler.Setup(rewardBlueprint);

    AddRewardToTile(rewardHandler as RewardHandler, tileHandler);
    tileHandler.currentAction = Action.Reward;

    return rewardHandler as RewardHandler;
}
```

The Setup for the base class (and most of all the inherited class)

```
public virtual void Setup(RewardBlueprint blueprint)
{
    type = blueprint.type;
    amount = Random.Range(blueprint.amount.min, blueprint.amount.max);
}
```

Then here is the Setup for a Weapon reward

```
internal override void ResolveReward(PlayerHandler playerHandler)
{
    base.ResolveReward(playerHandler);

    //Generate random stats weapon
    playerHandler.SetWeapon(new Weapon(damage, durability, effect));
}
```

NB: All my Reward prefabs have a specific Type: Coins, Gems, Weapon, Shield.

Comment: Overridden methods are called automatically, even when you don't know the specific Type. If that isn't your problem, edit with more detail.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that shows off your inheritance chain, your expected behaviour and the actual behaviour? That will help a lot in answering your question.

Comment: Well searching to get you a minimal example I found that I missed to do some assignments. So I fixed those and remove the hardcoded types and it works :)

Thank you both ! I feel a bit silly !